# Make a Character Counter for a QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to make a simple character counter, like the one in twitter, in QT specifically with the QLineEdit feature. Ideally, it should record the number of characters entered in a QLineEdit and display the number recorded in a separate display label. For example, spotify has a character counter when naming and adding a description to a playlist.

[image]

The function that I have declared to count the number of characters entered in the QLineEdit is defined like so:

```
void MainWindow::countChar()
{
    QString tempString = ui->displayLabel->text(); //temp variable to hold the lineEdit's text
    int output = tempString.size(); //to get the number of characters in the lineEdit
    QString s = QString::number(output);//convert an int to QString
    ui->CharCounter->setText(s); //display the number in the displayLabel(CharCounter)
    ui->CharCounter->adjustSize();
}
```

I call this function in my main.cpp under the object, w.

```
w.countChar();
```

The reason I want to create a character counter function is because I have set a character limit for the QLineEdit so whatever the user enters can be filled into the main displayLabel at the minimum size of the window. I have done that by writing another function:

```
void MainWindow::setlineInputTextCharLimit(int limit)
{
    ui->inputText->setMaxLength(limit);
}
```

Which I called under the same object, w:

```
w.setLineInputTextCharLimit(200);
```

QTCreator is able to successfully build but the charCounter displayLabel does not change in value after I enter some amount of text into the QLineEdit.

image of the application built

[image]

It is clear that the displayLabel for the character counter is being read and has been activated however when I enter any amount of text, the value does not change.

The result after there is some text entered into the QLineEdit

[image]

So if the displayLabel is registered and a value is being shown, the function should be working but there is definitely something wrong with it too because the value not change to anything from that '0'?.

Edit: the UI file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>554</width>
    <height>463</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>211</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="inputText"/>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="textBtn">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Display Text</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="displayLabel">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>100</width>
         <height>100</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="scaledContents">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="wordWrap">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="CharCounter">
       <property name="enabled">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>0</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="scaledContents">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="wordWrap">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>554</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

And heres the signal-slot connection:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->textBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::setText);
    connect(ui->inputText, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &MainWindow::countChar);
}
```

Comment: Where is your signal/slot conmection?

Comment: Looks like you want to count qlineedit, not qlabel in this string QString tempString = ui->displayLabel->text();

Comment: Just added my signal-slot connection. The "ui->displayLabel->text(); was wrong. That fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: Yep, just fixed that. Works like a charm now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to count the texts you must count each time the text changes and for that you must use the `textChanged()` signal, in the following code I show an example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>

class CounterWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText NOTIFY textChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int maxLenght READ maxLenght WRITE setMaxLenght)
    Q_PROPERTY(int length READ length)
public:
    CounterWidget(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        CounterWidget(200, parent)
    {
    }
    CounterWidget(int maxLength, QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QWidget(parent),
        layout(this)
    {
        layout.addWidget(&lineEdit);
        layout.addWidget(&counterLabel, 0, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignRight);
        connect(&lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &CounterWidget::countChar);
        connect(&lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &CounterWidget::textChanged);
        lineEdit.setMaxLength(maxLength);
        countChar("");
    }
    QString text() const{
        return lineEdit.text();
    }
    void setText(const QString &text){
        lineEdit.setText(text);
    }
    int maxLenght() const{
        return  lineEdit.maxLength();
    }
    void setMaxLenght(int maxLenght){
        lineEdit.setMaxLength(maxLenght);
    }
    int length() const{
        return lineEdit.text().size();
    }
signals:
    void textChanged(const QString & text);
private slots:
    void countChar(const QString & text){
        QString text_label = QString("%1/%2").arg(text.size()).arg(lineEdit.maxLength());
        counterLabel.setText(text_label);
    }
private:
    QVBoxLayout layout;
    QLineEdit lineEdit;
    QLabel counterLabel;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CounterWidget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I just added the textChanged() signal, the program still will not count the amount of characters entered into the QLineEdit. You can see the signal-slot connection. I'm also referencing your example.

Comment: @INeedHelpFrequently change `QString tempString = ui->displayLabel->text();` to  `QString tempString = ui->inputText->text();`. You are counting the QLabel texts instead of the QLineEdit.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the text from QLabel and not QLineEdit. So the part in my code:

```
QString tempString = ui->displayLabel->text();
```

was only reading the text from the label when I wanted to read the text entered in the QLineEdit. So I changed the code to:

```
QString tempString = ui->inputText->text();
```

and that fixed the problem. 
Thanks @FrozenM and @eyllanesc